# How to get rid of Skype for Business?

Tags: microsoft-office, skype, uninstall

How do I uninstall [image] ?
I don't remember having installed it and it doesn't even work:
[image]

There is no entry under *Programs and Features* in the Control Panel: 
[image]

I also checked the my Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 installer and under *Add/Remove features* I could find Word, Excel etc, but no Skype.

So how do I get rid of it? oO

Comment: It comes with Microsoft Office.

Comment: @Forivin What is crashing for you is a part of Office 365 suite and you cannot uninstall it.

Comment: @Forivin  You clearly have Office installed.  So what version do you have installed specifically?

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013

Comment: You have something other then Office 2013 installed since you would `Lync 2013` installed not `Skype for Business` (<sic> Lynch 2015)

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I don't really care. Skype for Business was removed when I uninstalled the Lynch that was listed in my Office 2013 installer/uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

This skype for buisness is actually called Lync, try searching for that also Lync (Skype for buisness is part of the Offices 365 package i have it too)

You should not be able to uninstall it without uninstalling office,

You could just disable it in Taskmanager>Startup Items>Skype for Buisness

Or try deleting the files manually (wich i would'nt really recomment) since it still has hidden files etc.

Comment: I don't have Office 365 and Skye for Business is not in my startup. But I was able to uninstall Lync using the Office installer/uninstaller and now SKype for Business is gone. :)

Comment: Ah good to hear

Comment: `Skype for Business` is not called `Lync`, considering Microsoft changed the name of `Lync` to `Skype for Business` before the release of Office 2015.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9h02z1 the exe is still called Lync for some reason then?